# removeClass('active') when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I am using this code to control the display of a sidebar via add/remove class.

The first 2 functions work, however I have also added a 3rd function to try to remove class active when clicking outside of the sidebar.

Now nothing works, it just pushes some body content aside.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".btn-open-sidecart").click(function(){
        $('.sidebar').addClass("active");
        $('.overlay').addClass("active");
    });

    $(".btn-close-sidecart").click(function(){ 
        $('.sidebar').removeClass("active");
        $('.overlay').removeClass("active");
    });

    $('body').click(function(event){
        if($(event.target).attr('class') !== "sidebar" && $(event.target).attr('class') !== "btn-close-sidecart") {
            $('.sidebar').removeClass('active');
            $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
        };
    });
});
```

How can I fix this to also `removeClass('active')` when clicking outside the sidebar?

Comment: I suspect your issue is that you're not clicking directly on the `sidebar` (eg clicking on the `btn-close-sidecart`).  Or that the `event.target` does not have *exactly* "sidebar" and may have other classes.   You could try `$(event.target).hasClass("sidebar")`   Or you could try `&& $(event.target).closest(".sidebar").length === 0` - ie check if the event target is *inside* the sidebar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: well the click propagates out the the element up to the body and you remove it.... Stop the event from propagating....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only checking if the element you are clicking on is ".sidebar" or ".btn-close-sidecart" but not if one of their parents has these class.

So even clicking on a button inside ".sidebar" will trigger your method as they are note ".sidebar"

Here is a working example

```js
$(".btn-open-sidecart").click(function(){
    $('.sidebar').addClass("active");
    $('.overlay').addClass("active");
});

$(".btn-close-sidecart").click(function(){ 
    $('.sidebar').removeClass("active");
    $('.overlay').removeClass("active");
});

$('body').click(function(event){
  const ignoreElements = ["btn-open-sidecart", "sidebar"];
  let pass = true;

  $(ignoreElements).each(function(key, value) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass(value) || $(event.target).closest(`.${value}`).length > 0) {
      pass = false;
    }
  });

  if (pass) {
    $('.sidebar').removeClass('active');
    $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: darkgrey
}

.sidebar:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}

.btn-close-sidecart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}

.overlay:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="btn-close-sidecart">
    x
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button onclick="console.log('test')">button 1</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button onclick="console.log('test2')">button 2</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <button class="btn-open-sidecart">Open sidebar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```